# viewWithTag returns nil for UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, viewwithtag

I have a `UITableView` with a prototype `UITableViewCell` with the identifier `contact`. In interface builder, I built the cell correctly and have all the elements set to the right tags. When I try to edit a `UILabel` in the cell that has the tag 101 using `cell.viewWithTag`, the method returns nil. This seems to only be a problem on iOS 8. I am using storyboards and Swift. Here is the code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
println("Contact: \(contact)")
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contact") as UITableViewCell
(cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) as UILabel).text = contact["name"]! as String
```

Comment: Why the down vote may I ask?

Comment: It works for me in a simple project. Try printing out your `contact["name"]` to see what's in it. Does your contact println work?

Comment: Yes, that prints it correctly

Comment: And your `contact["name"]` prints OK?

Comment: Yes, I also tried printing the description of the cell viewWithTag without casting it to a UILabel and it was still nil

Comment: I feel like this is an iOS 8 bug

Comment: Just checking: so you have TableView -> Cell -> Content View -> Label in your Storyboard? And your Label has the tag 101? I have that and it works for me. Try it in a simple new project, assigning a "String" instead of a variable to the label. It's working for me in Swift and iOS 8.

Comment: Yes I have all that. What's weird is that I also have cells that are working.

Comment: I'll try to create a new cell from scratch and see if that works

Comment: can you post the full UITableView class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use this

```
let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
println("Contact: \(contact)")
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contact", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
(cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) as UILabel).text = contact["name"]! as String
```

Comment: I did try this and it didn't work. Could you explain the difference between the method I was using and that method?

Comment: Wait, it just worked on another cell I was having problems with. Weird huh?

Comment: Actually, I am using (cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel).text = "some text.." which works great.